# Bootstrap input group addon alignment

Tags: bootstrap-4

How to align the icon in the center of input-group-addon?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            </center><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="password">
        </div>
        <div class="mt-2">
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mr-5">登入</a>
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ml-5">註冊</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer your question. Please could you provide a more complete example?

Comment: What have you actually tried? And it would be better to give a rough layout of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It's work well when I add a CSS style in the head. like this:

.input-group .input-group-addon .fa {width:4vh;position:center;}

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDLmL.jpg)